# Ruby on Rails: How can i change contents of a file after renaming the project name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Suppose i started a project name "abcd" doing this "rails new abcd".

So some configuration files are created by default with the name "abcd".

After few months if i change the project name to "xyz".

Then will the contents of those configuration files be changed automatically ?

How how can i change those line with "abcd" to "xyz".

Or is there any command to change these lines automatically ?

Suppose the config.ru =>

```
  3 require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
  4 run Abc::Application
```

Not it would be =>

```
  3 require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
  4 run Xyz::Application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally do that with my text editor - Find in files / replace "Abc" by "Xyz".

Comment: Right now I use vim + multiple plugins, but it has a steep curve. Ultraedit has this functionality and it's available on windows, mac & linux.